# how to add a value on uilabel with existing value and display it?

Tags: ios

I am getting a value from uipickerview and set it on uilabel of uitableviewcell, now i want that if i again get value from picker view than add it to previous value.

Here is my code for cell index:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UitableviewcellTableViewCell *Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(position == indexPath.row){

    NSString *old  = Cell.nameLabel.text = value;

    int val = [old intValue];

    NSLog(@"val %d", val);



   // Cell.nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", val+];


   }else{
      Cell.nameLabel.text = @"value";
   }
  NSLog(@"Position :- %ld   %d", (long)indexPath.row, position);

  return Cell;
}
```

This is the code for picker view form where i get value;

```
  - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
 {

    [self.mytableview reloadData];
    [self hidePickerView];
    NSLog(@"row selected:%ld", (long)row);
    value = _countingarray[row];

 }
```

Comment: u want to append to label value or addition of values and show it to label?

Comment: i want addition of values .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  value = @"0";
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
  NSLog(@"row selected:%ld", (long)row);
  value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[value intval] + [_countingarray[row] intval]];
  [self.mytableview reloadData];
  [self hidePickerView];

}   


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UitableviewcellTableViewCell *Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Cell.nameLabel.text = value;
    NSLog(@"%@", value);
    return Cell;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, i want you to clarify my question again. for example i select 3 from picker view and it display on uilabel when i will again click on that label and select again 2 from picker view now the value should be 5 on uilabel.

Comment: its not working bro, cam you suggest me some other solution please

Comment: thanks for your response, it gives error on _countingarray[row] like that :- "arithmetic on pointer to interface id which is not a constant size for this architecture and platform  "

Comment: can u tell me value in  _countingarray ??

Comment: yes sir, this is the way by which set the values on picker view :-  "  _countingarray = @[@" 1", @" 2", @" 3", @" 4",@" 5", ]; "

Comment: thanks bro its working fine now, but i have one issue in it, i have a uilabel in uitableviewcell, i want different value for every cell uilabel, for example if i updated value for one cell and then click on another cell then the same value increased with new value

Comment: generate algorithm as per your requirement. i hope the problem u asked is solved

Comment: thanks bro i solved my problem, but i will be thankful to you if you help me one more situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSLog(@"row selected:%ld", (long)row);
    yourLabel.text = [yourLabel.text intVal] + [_countingarray[row] intVal];
    [self.mytableview reloadData];
    [self hidePickerView];

}
```

Comment: i want to add it from tableview cell method